# Black threads are coming of my tire. Does it need to be replaced?

Tags: tire, safety

One of my bike tires have started shedding long black threads. I'm assuming that this means that something is not right. The tire has a folding bead. Does this mean that my tire should be replaced as soon as possible, or is it nothing to worry about?

[image: Tire shedding fibers]

Comment: Photos would help.

Comment: Where on the tire are these "threads" coming from?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Should have clarified that. :) They are coming from the sidewall, near the rim.

Comment: You sometimes have a sprue (excess rubber due to a joint or vent in the mold) along the rim.  That can peel off with no harm.  The thing to beware of would be your brake pad rubbing on the tire sidewall (the pad should *only* contact the metal rim, never the side of the tire).

Comment: How old is it?  How much use has it had?  What brand/model?

Answer (score 3):

That's thread from the layer of fabric they use to cover the tire bead, they sometimes fray a  little, just cut them off, they're not part of the tire structure.